# Perform calculation iteratively over rows in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, vector

I have a dataframe with a column called 'letter' and another 'vector' containing vectors, all the same length, that correspond to the letters. (The actual dataset has many, many more columns and the vectors are larger.)

```
            letter    vector
0              a         [2.5, 4.7, 235, 46, 34]
1              a         [2.5, 5, 234, 345.8, 1]
2              a         [2.5, 5, 234, 432.6, 1]
3              i         [4.7, 34.2, 3, 34, 700]
4              u         [4.7, 123, 123, 13, 66]
5              u         [4.7, 13, 375, 123, 66]
6              i         [4.7, 15, 375, 23, 656]
```

I would like to perform a calculation between each vector in turn. For example, calculate the Euclidean distance between the vectors in row 0 and row 1, row 1 and 2, etc. The catch is that I want to do perform this process 3 separate times - once for only the letter 'a' vectors, once for only the letter 'i' vectors, etc.

I can run a for loop for each unique letter value:

```
for l in df['letter'].unique():
```

but I got lost trying to iterate the calculation through the subset of rows.

Comment: What have you tried? Some code?

Comment: We need more information on the context of how your dataset is set up in code, and how your using it for more tailored responses.

Comment: Ok, I've added some code I attempted but I really did include a miniature version of the dataframe that I'm looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a dataset composed of 2D elements (first index is column, second is values), this would work.  As per your question:

> For example, calculate the Euclidean distance between the vectors in row 0 and row 1, row 1 and 2, row 2 and 3, etc

So, while this doesn't add up the Euclidian distance, it does add val0 from row0 to val0 from row1, val1 from row0 to val1 in row1, etc on through all the rows, stopping at n-1 columns.  If you want more specific help, you'll have to provide more code context, variables, how your dataset is stored, etc.

```
for index in range(0, len(dataset)-1):
        for sub_index in range(0, len(dataset[index])):
            // Perform your logic/math/whatever here.
            print(dataset[index][sub_index]+dataset[index+1][sub_index])
```

Using the example dataset you provided, I had to truncate the 'i' row by 1, as it had 6 elements, and the rest had 5.

I got the following output:

```
5.0
9.7
469
391.8
35
7.2
39
237
379.8
8
9.4
157
126
47
73
```

Which is expected.

Comment: It's probably my own lack of explanation, but I don't know what you're referring to with 'val0 from row 1' or 'val1 from row0' - I'm just looking for a way to calculate something between the vector in row 0 and the vector in row 1.

Comment: That's....what I was explaining.  A vector has values in it.  A vector has a series of stored values.  Your example of a vector has a series of values.  2.5 is the first value in the first row.